# Divi : Limit Click Times Button

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to limits the times click on button in divi theme in wordpress but don't know how and I need help. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. Please show us what you have tried with code. It is easier to help you then.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Divi for this, just add a simple javascript at your code to track the clicks.

Supposing that you are using jQuery, here is the code.

```
var clicks = 0;
var maxClicks = 3; // set the maximum time to be clicked
var elementClassSelector = '.your-class-button';

$(elementClassSelector).on('click', function(e){
  // prevent the event if we already have enought clicks
  if (clicks >= maxClicks) {
   e.preventDefault();  
  } else {
   clicks++ // increase the number of clicks
  }
})
```

Here is a [link](https://divi.works/custom-scripts-in-divi/) how to add a custom javascript using Divi.

Here is a [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/) to help you add javascript or CSS in any theme.